# Python reading complex nested json values

Tags: python, json

I am writing a script which runs a set of different linux commands in a certain category.
For instance, commands which give system information, are in a category called SYS_INFO.

I am using a dictionary to define the commands (and more information about them) like so

```
dictionary = {
              "SYS_INFO": {
                 "Uname": {
                    "msg":"Kernel Version Information", 
                    "cmd":"uname -a"
                  },
                  "OS": {
                     "msg":"Operating System Information",
                     "cmd":"cat /etc/issue"
                  },
               "NET_INFO": { 
                     etc... 
               }
              }
```

I need to loop through the dictionary and get the "category" (Uname, OS) and the associated information for them (msg, cmd), for the different information (SYS_INFO, NET_INFO).

How can I iterate over the dictionary, and get the required information?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is is this:

```
for k1 in dictionary:
    for k2 in dictionary[k1]:
        print k1, k2, dictionary[k1][k2]
```

Another way is

```
for k1, d1 in dictionary.items():
    for k2, v in d1.items():
        print k1, k2, v
```